# Css problem in Mui Component Implementation

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a vertical timeline using Material UI in React.
I implemented it but the css does not work. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Dependencies;
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.8",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.143",
"@mui/material": "^5.14.8",
"@emotion/core": "^10.0.7",
"@emotion/styled": "^10.3.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "^4.0.0",

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Timeline from '@mui/lab/Timeline';
import TimelineItem from '@mui/lab/TimelineItem';
import TimelineSeparator from '@mui/lab/TimelineSeparator';
import TimelineConnector from '@mui/lab/TimelineConnector';
import TimelineContent from '@mui/lab/TimelineContent';
import TimelineDot from '@mui/lab/TimelineDot';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import TimelineOppositeContent from '@mui/lab/TimelineOppositeContent';

class Template1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
                <Timeline position="alternate">
                    <TimelineItem>
                        <TimelineOppositeContent color="text.secondary">
                            09:30 am
                        </TimelineOppositeContent>
                        <TimelineSeparator>
                            <TimelineDot />
                            <TimelineConnector />
                        </TimelineSeparator>
                        <TimelineContent>Eat</TimelineContent>
                    </TimelineItem>
                    <TimelineItem>
                        <TimelineOppositeContent color="text.secondary">
                            10:00 am
                        </TimelineOppositeContent>
                        <TimelineSeparator>
                            <TimelineDot />
                            <TimelineConnector />
                        </TimelineSeparator>
                        <TimelineContent>Code</TimelineContent>
                    </TimelineItem>
                    <TimelineItem>
                        <TimelineOppositeContent color="text.secondary">
                            12:00 am
                        </TimelineOppositeContent>
                        <TimelineSeparator>
                            <TimelineDot />
                            <TimelineConnector />
                        </TimelineSeparator>
                        <TimelineContent>Sleep</TimelineContent>
                    </TimelineItem>
                    <TimelineItem>
                        <TimelineOppositeContent color="text.secondary">
                            9:00 am
                        </TimelineOppositeContent>
                        <TimelineSeparator>
                            <TimelineDot />
                            <TimelineConnector />
                        </TimelineSeparator>
                        <TimelineContent>Repeat</TimelineContent>
                    </TimelineItem>
                </Timeline>
            </StyledEngineProvider>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    socketUrl: state.behavior.get('socketUrl')
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Template1);
```

I get the component codes from here but it doesn't work
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-timeline/

Comment: "Does not work" is not a technical description of a problem. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

To change the text color, you need to apply `color="secondary"` instead of `color="text.secondary"`.

Comment: Actually, this is not my problem. All css is not working. Component loads completely without css.

Comment: OK, you will need to set up a CodeSandbox or a GitHub repo with your problem if you'd like me to help further.